# Nuxtjs change default UI framework

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I got a nuxtjs project and I selected bootstrapvue as my UI framework. But now I want to change my UI framework to vuesax since I dont like some of bootstrapvue components. What I did was I deleted the bootstrapvue config in my package.json then I got sudden errors. Now I reverted it back and in my config i got two UI framework and when I use vuesax tags it doest work. Any help for this? Thanks.

package.json as of now

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.3.6",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.0-0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "vuesax": "^4.0.1-alpha.18"
  },
```

Errors

```
 ERROR  in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css                                                                                                      friendly-errors 02:22:30

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):                                                                                              friendly-errors 02:22:30
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Vince\Desktop\nuxtTest\node_modules\bootstrap-vue\dist\bootstrap-vue.css'

 ERROR  in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css                                                                                                          friendly-errors 02:22:30

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):                                                                                              friendly-errors 02:22:30
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Vince\Desktop\nuxtTest\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css'

 ERROR  in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/index.js                                                                                                                friendly-errors 02:22:30

Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Vince\Desktop\nuxtTest\node_modules\bootstrap-vue\esm\index.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you remove `bootstrap-vue/nuxt` from your `nuxt.config.js` [modules](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-modules)?

You should share your error messages with us. One misc debugging procedure I do is `rm -rf` the `.nuxt` folder and relaunch the dev server.

Comment: i didnt remove it. should i remove it? what should i replace after?

Comment: @Vince You should remove it because when you have it nuxt tries to load bootstrap-vue but you removed bootstrap-vue from the project so it cannot find it and it errors. Adding Vuesax is more tricky since it doesn't provide a nuxt module. You should do some reading on nuxt modules and plugins and SSR. The best place for this is the official nuxt documentation https://nuxtjs.org/guide. Also this https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax/issues/83#issuecomment-391526509

Comment: error message posted. also if i remove bootstrap vue what should be the replacement?

Comment: @Vince check my updated comment. You should do some reading on Nuxt modules and plugins and check the Github issue link I linked to.